# how to join two dataframe with a key and duplicate the matching value to fill in

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

how can I join two data frames by column "ID" and fill the blanks with the matching value. Since it is complicated to explain, here is my code to show what I want for the result.

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], 'col1': [3, 0, -1, 3.4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'col2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']})
```

Now, I want to join these two dataframes with "id" and duplicate the values in col2 to fill in the blank col2 column after join.

please help me. Thanks

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `merge`?

```
df.merge(df2, on='id')

    id  col1    col2
0   1   3.0     A
1   1   0.0     A
2   1   -1.0    A
3   2   3.4     B
4   2   4.0     B
5   3   5.0     C
6   4   6.0     D
7   4   7.0     D
8   4   8.0     D
```

Comment: Simplest and easiest way to do merging

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['col2'] = df['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['col2'])
```

Or left join with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = df.merge(df2, on='id', how='left')
```

---

```
print (df)
   id  col1 col2
0   1   3.0    A
1   1   0.0    A
2   1  -1.0    A
3   2   3.4    B
4   2   4.0    B
5   3   5.0    C
6   4   6.0    D
7   4   7.0    D
8   4   8.0    D
```

Answer (score 0):

If you outer join them:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df, df2, on='id', how='outer')
```

Then you can replace `NaN` values in `col1` by corresponding values in `col2`:

```
df3.loc[df3.col1.isnull(), 'col1'] = df3.loc[df3.col1.isnull(), 'col2']
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
    id col1 col2
0   1   3   A
1   1   0   A
2   1   -1  A
3   2   3.4 B
4   2   4   B
5   3   5   C
6   4   6   D
7   4   7   D
8   4   8   D
9   5   E   E
10  6   F   F
11  7   G   G
12  8   H   H
13  9   I   I
```